# Resetting an EventListner?

Tags: javascript

So I have this code in my typing test website,

```
testArea.addEventListener(
    "input",
    () => {
        // Converting minutes to milliseconds
        startTimer(userMinutes * 60 * 100);
    },
    { once: true }
);
```

I need the {once:true} to prevent the timer from starting up on EACH user input into the testArea.
This becomes a problem when I click the restart button since the the eventListener was already typed once, it doesn't start the timer after starting the timer, clicking the restart button.

So my question is, is there a way to reset that eventListener so that when a user clicks the "reset button" it resets that eventListner so that the timer will start after the user clicks the reset button.

Or is there a different DOM I can use to make this work.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried [`removeEventListener()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp)?

Comment: `userMinutes * 60000` would be milliseconds, but that's not really your question. Don't use the `{once:true}`, and just set a variable, or remove and add the Event again with the `{once:true}`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a function  and inside that add event listener event to the input. Then on `reset` call the same function and reattach the event

```
function reset() {
  testArea.removeEventListener();
  addEvent();
}

function addEvent() {
  testArea.addEventListener(
    "input",
    () => {
      // Converting minutes to milliseconds
      startTimer(userMinutes * 60 * 100);
    }, {
      once: true
    }
  );
}
}
```

Comment: I added removeEventListener("input", startTime(), false) and it's not doing anything

Comment: EDIT: So i forgot to use the addEvent timer, and it works, but a weird bug occured. When i click the restart button more than once the timer doesn't stop anymore...